# (adb) How to queue commands for the next recovery boot?

Tags: android, adb

How to create a queue of commands that will run immediately the next time I boot into the recovery?

I have tried this command from [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201862/permission-denied-when-working-with-without-su-c-in-cache/201865) by [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord)

```
adb shell 'su -c "'"echo "boot-recovery" > /cache/recovery/command"'"'
```

and I added more based on it

```
adb shell 'su -c "'"echo "--update_package=/sdcard/file.zip" > /cache/recovery/command"'"'
```

Then

```
adb reboot recovery
```

The result was the file `/cache/recovery/command` containing

```
boot-recovery
--update_package=/sdcard/file.zip
```

and the phone reboots into recovery but nothing happens...

**Is this even the right way to do it?** Please correct me, I am not so good (pretty bad) at android recovery commands

**More info:** TWRP 3.2, Android 8.1, 9.0, 10.0